# Scraping table data from a list of URLs (each containing a unique table) for the purposes of appending it all to a single list/dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, statistics, data-science

I am scraping data from a list of hundreds of URLs, each one containing a table with statistical baseball data. Within each unique URL in the list, there is a table for all of the seasons of a single baseball player's career, like this:

https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/killeha01.shtml

I have successfully created a script to append the data from **a single URL** into a single list/dataframe. However, here is my question:

How should I adjust my code to scrape **a full list** of hundreds of URLs from this domain and then append all of the table rows from all of the URLs into a single list/dataframe?

My general format for scraping a single URL is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_baseball_players = ['https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/killeha01.shtml']

def scrape_baseball_data(url_parameter):

    html = urlopen(url_parameter)

    # create the BeautifulSoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    column_headers = [SCRAPING COMMAND WITH CSS SELECTOR GADGET FOR GETTING COLUMN HEADERS]

    table_rows = soup.select(SCRAPING COMMAND WITH CSS SELECTOR GADGET FOR GETTING ALL OF THE DATA FROM THE TABLES INCLUDING HTML CHARACTERS)

    player_data = []

    for row in table_rows:  

        player_list = [COMMANDS FOR SCRAPING HTML DATA FROM THE TABLES INTO AN ORGANIZED LIST]

        if not player_list:
            continue

        player_data.append(player_list)

    return player_data

list_baseball_player_data = scrape_baseball_data(url_baseball_players)

df_baseball_player_data = pd.DataFrame(list_baseball_player_data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `url_baseball_players` is a list of all the URLs you want to scrape, and your expected output is one data frame (where you append, row-wise, each new URL's data), then just keep adding with `concat()` as you iterate over URLs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for url in url_baseball_players:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(scrape_baseball_data(url))])
```

Comment: This is such an elegant solution. I really thought I had to change the code within the function and didn't even realize it was possible to do a for loop in the call for the function. Thanks!